# Select k rows with the highest value of a given column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's suppose you have a pandas dataframe with col1 and you want to keep only the k samples with the highest value of col1. How can you do that?

Notice I'm not saying maximum value. But rather like sorting by col1, keeping the best k samples, and removing the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k=10 # some number
df.sort_values('col', ascending=False).head(k)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I believe this will change the order of the index.

Comment: im sorta following you. Does it matter though? you needed a sample of highest value. if you post a reproducible example with expected output that help in answering.

Comment: Yes you're right in the end I didn't need it. I marked this as answered thanks!